# Problem with color changing in R using scale_fill_manual

Tags: r

I have  a dataset called temperature4countries

| Year | Spain | Cyprus | Iceland | Austria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | 15 | 17 | 7 | 8 |
| 1999 | 20 | 21 | 7.5 | 8.5 |
| 2000 | 16 | 18 | 7 | 8 |
| 2001 | 17 | 20 | 8 | 8 |
| 2002 | 17.5 | 19 | 8 | 8 |
| 2003 | 20 | 21 | 7.5 | 8.5 |
| 2004 | 20 | 22 | 8 | 9 |
| 2005 | 20 | 21 | 8.5 | 9.5 |
| 2006 | 21 | 27 | 9 | 10 |
| 2007 | 22 | 23 | 9.5 | 10.5 |
| 2008 | 25 | 24 | 9 | 11 |

```
temperature <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Year= c(1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008),
  Spain = c(15,20,16,17,17.5,20,20,20,21,22,25),
  Cyprus = c(17,21,18,20,19,21,22,21,27,23,24),
  Iceland = c(7,7.5,7,8,8,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,9),
  Austria = c(8,8.5,8,8,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11),
  check.names = FALSE
)
dput(temperature)
```

My goal is to create a line graph

I used that code

```
df <- pivot_longer(temperature, 
                        cols = c(Spain, Cyprus, Iceland, Austria), 
                        values_to = "Temperature",
                        names_to = "Countries")
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = Year,
         y = Temperature,
         color = Countries
       )) +
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle("Trend of Temperature in 4 European countries") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature[C]")
```

Again the colors are really ugly. I would like to change it.
I used that code

```
df <- pivot_longer(temperature, 
                        cols = c(Spain, Cyprus, Iceland, Austria), 
                        values_to = "Temperature",
                        names_to = "Countries")
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = Year,
         y = Temperature,
         color = Countries
       )) +
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle("Trend of Temperature in 4 European countries") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature[C]")  + scale_fill_manual(values=c("aqua marine", "teal","lime","yellow"))
```

But the colors didn't change???

Because I thought that this is the way how to change colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the color doesn't change is because you cannot use `scale_fill_manual`. Change it to `scale_color_manual` and you will see the change.

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = Year,
         y = Temperature,
         color = Countries
       )) +
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle("Trend of Temperature in 4 European countries") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature[C]") + scale_color_manual(values=c("aqua marine", "red","blue","yellow"))
```

Note: that I had to change some colors because it couldn't find "lime" and "teal".

PS. The difference between them is that:

- `scale_fill_manual()` is used for plots where you have things to
  fill, e.g. box plots, bar plots, violin plots, dot plots, etc.
- `scale_color_manual()` is used for lines and points.

Here more [info](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-colors-best-tricks-you-will-love/).

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scale_color_manual` in this case, instead of `scale_fill_manual`. Be explicit in your `values` param, passing a named vector:

```
+ scale_color_manual(values=c("Austria" = "red", "Cyprus" = "blue",
                             "Iceland" = "green","Spain" = "orange"))
```

Check `colors()` for named colors available. You could use `"#008080"` in place of `"teal"` and `"limegreen"` in place of `"lime"`, if you like.

Comment: yes, thanks the colors were wrong. many thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You're well on your way! You are making three mistakes:

1. You added `+` twice in a row in your last line of code
2. You are using `scale_fill_manual(...)`, but the aesthetic that is being used in the plot is `color`. Thus, the correct function would be `scale_colour_manual(...)`.
3. The colours that you specified are not R colours. You can get an overview of all named colours in R using `colors()`. Check an individual colour using e.g. `"aquamarine" %in% colors()`

Thus, the correct code would be:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(
         x = Year,
         y = Temperature,
         color = Countries
       )) +
  geom_line() + 
  ggtitle("Trend of Temperature in 4 European countries") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Temperature[C]") + scale_colour_manual(values=c("aquamarine", "cyan4","limegreen","yellow"))
```